# Appcelerator Facebook presentShareDialog wont open app

Tags: facebook, dialog, titanium, share, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator 4.9.1, with titanium SDK 6.1.2 and Facebook module 5.4.0 (latest), IOS 10.2.1, MacOS 10.11.6

when trying to share something, the web version of facebook opens, instead of the app. Already read all the guides and some fix made since version 6.0.0 of Titanium, but still, every time is the webview instead of the app.

I tried revisiting every step of implementing facebook in the app.

---

I tried doing it directly in Xcode with Swift 3

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func shareOnFacebook(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        let facebookShare: SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        facebookShare.setInitialText("Look at this great picture!")
        facebookShare.add(UIImage(named: "genghis-khan.jpg")!)
        facebookShare.add(URL(string: "https://mindware.com.mx"))
        self.present(facebookShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Account", message: "Please login to a facebook account to share", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

And this presents the following, now, how can i achieve this with appcelerator?
[Facebook post dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Qah.png)

---

titanium Code below.

```
fb.presentShareDialog(
  {
    link: 'https://example.org',
    title: 'Usual sharing operation'
  });
```

Here is the tiapp.xml

```
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
<id>org.example.appid</id>
<name>Ayuda Maistro</name>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<publisher>myusername</publisher>
<url>https://example.org</url>
<description>App para busqueda y contacto de trabajadores para hogar y oficina, mejor conocidos como maistros</description>
<copyright>2017 by xavieralfeiran</copyright>
<icon>appicon.png</icon>
<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
<analytics>true</analytics>
<guid>0df83aa3-e4ee-4fd8-9333-b12255351f75</guid>
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
<property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>
<ios>
    <enable-launch-screen-storyboard>false</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
    <use-app-thinning>true</use-app-thinning>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
            <string>
                Cenotes requiere tu ubicacion para mostrar las opciones cercanas
            </string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
            <string>
                Foto para el maistro
            </string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
            <string>
                Cenotes requiere tu ubicacion para mostrar las opciones cercanas
            </string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>facebook.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                </dict>
                <key>fbcdn.net</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                </dict>
                <key>akamaihd.net</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                    <!-- Application ID same as the id value in the tiapp.xml file -->
                    <string>mx.com.mindware.maistros</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <!-- Prefix the Facebook App ID with 'fb' -->
                        <string>fb175100632968910</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string>01010101010101</string>
            <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
            <string>Ayuda Maistro</string>
            <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fbapi</string>
                <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
                <string>fbauth2</string>
                <string>fbshareextension</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Advertisement would like to create a calendar event.</string>
            <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Advertisement would like to store a photo.</string>
            <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Advertisement would like to use the microphone.</string>
            <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Advertisement would like to query your music library.</string>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
<mobileweb>
    <precache/>
    <splash>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
    </splash>
    <theme>default</theme>
</mobileweb>
<modules>
    <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
    <module platform="iphone">dk.napp.drawer</module>
    <module platform="android">facebook</module>
    <module platform="iphone">facebook</module>
    <module platform="iphone">com.omorandi</module>
    <module platform="iphone">bencoding.securely</module>
    <module platform="android">bencoding.securely</module>
</modules>
<deployment-targets>
    <target device="android">true</target>
    <target device="ipad">true</target>
    <target device="iphone">true</target>
    <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
</deployment-targets>
<sdk-version>6.1.2.GA</sdk-version>
<plugins>
    <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
</plugins>
<property name="appc-app-id" type="string">5876c5577ac14b482657f078</property>
<property name="acs-authbase-url-development" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-base-url-development" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-development" type="string">ZceAWJMxRm9yJAw5bZaTBv3OZEik8R3X</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-development" type="string">btB9fHLlV3Tpg6LBAduDUGvw8UvJmr9u</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string">M8gXeJP5g3y7Cx0qz1Vmm8K4scrdeCfG</property>
<property name="acs-username-development" type="string">appc_app_user_dev</property>
<property name="acs-password-development" type="string">WWcOMANxIGZhgctMyt</property>
<property name="acs-authbase-url-production" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-base-url-production" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-production" type="string">FIK1V2R5TdOxbVfVT8H23I0QAX2LakVp</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-production" type="string">nih1B6eEWaT9WfWr3bLJPEViqnO0jQSq</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">38RjD4LsKqh60zjLPontOjFTT6uX6FmJ</property>
<property name="acs-username-production" type="string">appc_app_user</property>
<property name="acs-password-production" type="string">E8Q4dWf5Ox8XG0ncup</property>
<property name="appc-org-id" type="string">100012327</property>
<property name="appc-creator-user-id" type="string">f8b4c614-11df-4a05-ad92-9612c8f0c9dc</property>
</ti:app>
```

I even logged out of Facebook in safari, but no luck

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the mobile you are trying to open the **shareDialog** has the Facebook Mobile App Installed on it. Because the only case it won't work, considering that you have implemented everything including the entries in the `tiapp.xml`.

Comment: Yes, i use it more than i should haha. I thought that was something about permissions. I logged out from safari (only with facebook app). I'm updating the post to include the tiapp.xml

Comment: The strange thing happens, when i login with FB, the app do opens and ask me to allow the app to use for login, but once inside my app and hit share, safari shows up.

Comment: one Issue that I see in your tiapp.xml is `<key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string>01010101010101</string>`, the id here should be the same that you have added above. (i.e. `<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <!-- Prefix the Facebook App ID with 'fb' -->
                        <string>fb175100632968910</string>
                    </array>`)

Comment: it is the same, just without the fb prefix.